# How to break a playing sound when switching activity?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a list array adapter.I use a template layout for each elements of "arraylist".I play sound by "onclicklistener" defined on image in my "CustomArrayAdapter.java" class.
by the way i define "onStop()" as override in related activity.
when i click on image,sound plays,but when i test switching activity by hitting home button on mobile,
sound continue playing.
part of my code in Customarraylist.java :

```
ImageView playIconSecondLanguageImage =      (ImageView)list_layout.findViewById(R.id.playIconsecondLanguageImageviewId);  playIconSecondLanguageImage.setImageResource(customWord.getmPlayIconImageId();
playIconSecondLanguageImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
 releaseMediaPlayer();// to stop another playing when another start instantly
     mMediaPlayer = 
    MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext(),customWord.getmSecondLanguageSoundId());
      mMediaPlayer.start();
      mOnCompletionListener();
            }
        });
```

and part of my code in NumberActivity.java:

```
  }//End of Oncreat

   public void releaseMediaPlayer(){
        if(mediaPlayer!=null)
        {
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }
    }

   protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        releaseMediaPlayer();
    }
}//End of  class NumbersActivity
```

problem is that mediaplayer in NumbersActivity.java is different whith mediaplayer which i defined in
"Customarraylist.java" to play sound.
my CustomArrayAdapter.java is:

```
package com.example.customarrayadapter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Application;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CustomWord> {
//    States
    private int mColorId;
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
//  to avoid creat new object(here,new medaPlayer), this codes below take out from the Onclick listener
//    and define here******************
    private MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener mOnCompletionListener = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Play finished!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //                        check is it need to mPlayer anymore or not,to free up memeory usage by the player
            releaseMediaPlayer();
        }
    };


    //****************************************
//    need Constructor
    public CustomArrayAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<CustomWord>arrayList,int colorId){
        super(context,0,arrayList);
        this.mColorId = colorId;
    }

//    use getView override method to move elements of arraylist one by one by its position,to listview
//    getView method, steps:
//    a. get position of elements in "customWord"(get one from 2 elements in CustomWord" Type,and pass to
//    arraylist of type CustomWord,then 2 from 2 elemnts moves),by "position" by "getItem(position)"

//    b. prepare a view (convertview),to locate our "list_layout", in it
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
//        a.
        final CustomWord customWord = getItem(position);
//        Define "list_layout"  view, to get  "convertView" layout in it
        View list_layout = convertView;
//        if list_layout is null,then put "customlist_layout" in it
        if(list_layout==null){
            list_layout = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.customlist_layout,parent,false);
        }
//        1 image (source image) + 2 words + 2 image(language flags) +  2 images(olay icon), in customlist_layout.xml so ,so need 2 textview + 1 imageview

        // Find the ImageView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID list_item_icon
//         ImageView 1 (SourceImage)
        ImageView ImageSourceiconView = (ImageView) list_layout.findViewById(R.id.ImageSourceViewId);
        // set the image to iconView
        ImageSourceiconView.setImageResource(customWord.getmDataResourceId());

        //        put elements(2 elements) in "CustomWord" one by one into (2 textviews),each textview (one textview to second textview)
//      textview 1
        TextView secondLanguage_tv = (TextView)list_layout.findViewById(R.id.SecondLanguageId_Textview_ListView);
        secondLanguage_tv.setText(customWord.getmSecondLanguageString());
//      textview 2
        TextView defualtLanguage_tv = (TextView)list_layout.findViewById(R.id.DefualtLanguageId_Textview_ListView);
        defualtLanguage_tv.setText(customWord.getmDefualtLanguageString());

//        Default Flag Language Image View
        //         ImageView 2 (Default Flag)
        ImageView defaultLanguageFlag = (ImageView) list_layout.findViewById(R.id.DefaultLanguageFlag);
        // set the image to iconView
        defaultLanguageFlag.setImageResource(customWord.getmDefaultLanguageFlag());

//        Second Flag Language ImageView
        //         ImageView 3 (Second Flag)
        ImageView secondLanguageFlag = (ImageView) list_layout.findViewById(R.id.SecondLanguageFlag);
        // set the image to iconView
        secondLanguageFlag.setImageResource(customWord.getmSecondLanguageFlag());

        // source playIcon imageview

        ImageView playIconDefualtLanguageImage = (ImageView)list_layout.findViewById(R.id.playIcondefaultLanguageImageViewId);
        playIconDefualtLanguageImage.setImageResource(customWord.getmPlayIconImageId());

        playIconDefualtLanguageImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                releaseMediaPlayer();// to stop another playing when another start instantly
                mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext(),customWord.getmDefaultLanguageSoundId());
                mMediaPlayer.start();
                mOnCompletionListener();
            }
        });
        // 2nd play icon image set
        ImageView playIconSecondLanguageImage = (ImageView)list_layout.findViewById(R.id.playIconsecondLanguageImageviewId);
        playIconSecondLanguageImage.setImageResource(customWord.getmPlayIconImageId());

        playIconSecondLanguageImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                releaseMediaPlayer();// to stop another playing when another start instantly
                mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext(),customWord.getmSecondLanguageSoundId());
                mMediaPlayer.start();
                mOnCompletionListener();
            }
        });


        //        Default Sound Language Image View
        //         ImageView 4 (Default Language sound)

//         set color of layout by mcolorId to sync with name of category in main layout.xml
        View textContainer  = list_layout.findViewById(R.id.CustomListId);
//        ContextCompat is for creat color from getColor
//        getColor get color of getContext Object and its color integer id
        int color = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),mColorId);
        textContainer.setBackgroundColor(color);


        return list_layout;
    }//End of getviw

    private void mOnCompletionListener() {
    }

    public void releaseMediaPlayer(){
        if(mMediaPlayer!=null)
        {
            mMediaPlayer.release();
            mMediaPlayer = null;
        }
    }


    public void setmMediaPlayer(MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer) {
        this.mMediaPlayer = mMediaPlayer;
    }
    public MediaPlayer getmMediaPlayer() {
        return mMediaPlayer;
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry but your question is unclear, what exactly you want, you want to stop the song when you hit the home button or switching to another Activity ?

Comment: by switching to another Activity

Comment: I got it now, you can do it using Interface, post your whole code of adapter I will help you out to manage your needs

Answer (score 0):

You have to control activity lifecycles and then you have to switch on/off sound accordingly to your needs.

[enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)

Comment: control activity lifecycles is not possible for my code. bcz my playing is not start from activity,it starts from "CustomArrayAdapter.java" codes.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your needs using `Interface` :

Create an `Interface` and call it (e.g. **PlayerCallBack**) :

```
public interface PlayerCallBack {
    void onMediaPlayerClickEvent(int position);
}
```

In your `CustomArrayAdapter` add a `constructor` as follows :

```
public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, PlayerCallBack playerCallBack, ArrayList<CustomWord> customWords) {
        this.context = context;
        this.playerCallBack = playerCallBack;
        this.customWords = customWords;
    }
```

Change the code of `ImageView` click listener to this :

```
 playIconSecondLanguageImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                playerCallBack.onMediaPlayerClickEvent(position);
            }
        });
```

In your `NumbersActivity` :

```
 CustomArrayAdapter customArrayAdapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(customWords, getApplicationContext(), new PlayerCallBack() {
            @Override
            public void onMediaPlayerClickEvent(int position) {
                mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext(), customWord.getmSecondLanguageSoundId());
                mMediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });
```

No you can play with `MediaPlayer` as you want

Comment: customWord in customWord.getmSecondLanguageSoundId(), is unknown variable.

Comment: @M.JJalali I just provide an example, if you want the complete solution, add the adapter code, CustomWord model class to your question,

Comment: i did the corrections codes. but still sound is playing while i hit the mobile Home Button or change the activity. where is onStop() override method?

Answer (score 0):

After googling i found a solution to this.
sound source is playing in "CustomArrayAdapter.java" class that is set in NumbersActivity.java class as Activity. after clicking on image to play sound,sound is playing, when hit "Home" mobile button ,Activating "Activity:NumbersActivity",goes in
onPause then onStop state. but sound is playing.
one way is to find process running in background when "Home" button is hitted.
and that is "com.example.customarrayadapter",so i can find the process and kill it by its id  :
codes are written in Activity: NumbersActivity

```
 } //End Of Oncreate

  protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> services = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();
        String service1name = services.get(0).processName;
        int processPid = services.get(0).pid;
        Log.d("*Process PID*","**********");
        Log.d(activityNameString,"onStop invoked");
        Log.d(activityNameString,"Process Id is : "+service1name+"\n");
        android.os.Process.killProcess(processPid);

    }
}//End of NumbersActivity class
```